# Framework 7 Vue - Run Parent Vue's Methods not working

Tags: vue.js, methods, html-framework-7

I have tried a lot of different ways to run a simple function from parent vue but still not working, console.log no error but nothing happen...anyone please help me have a look on this...thanks a lot.

app.vue

```
import childpage from './child.vue';
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            f7params: {
              name: 'myapp',
              id: 'com.myapp.fn',
              theme : 'ios',
              routes: [
                  {
                    path: '/childpage/',
                    component: childpage,
                  },
        }
    },
    events:{
        fn : 'runfn',
    },
    methods: {
        runfn(){
            console.log('HERE!!!');
        }
    },
    components: {
        childpage,
    }
}
```

child.vue

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            isBottom: true,
        };
    },
    mounted: function(){
        this.runfn();
    },
    methods: {
        runfn(){ 
            this.$emit('fn');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try as below =>

```
this.$parent.runfn();
```

Below is the detailed code.

Template

```
<div id="app">
  <child></child>
</div>
```

Script

```
Vue.component('child', {
  template: '#child-template',
   mounted: function(){
       this.$parent.runfn();
    },
});

var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
  methods: {
    runfn(){
        alert('parent');
    }
    }
});
```

Refer this for more details. https://jsfiddle.net/RiddhiParekh/onkzr3ms/3/

Comment: showing this error:
[Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: this.$parent.runfn is not a function"

Comment: Remove this line => this.runfn(); from mounted function. Update  as => mounted: function(){
       this.$parent.runfn();
    },

Comment: Do you mean parent methods cannot be use in child mounted event?

Comment: You can use parent methods in mounted of child component.Please check updated fiddle.